# Differenzierte Übersetzung der Begriffe Wizard, Sorcerer und Warlock

Tags: translation, english-to-german, literature

Es gibt im Englischen die Begriffe **Wizard**, **Sorcerer** und **Warlock** welche je nach Benutzung/Genre (in der Fantasy-Welt) leicht nuancierte Bedeutungen haben, die nicht durchweg konsistent zu sein scheinen.
Mir scheint aber, dass man als gemeinsamen Nenner der Begriffe den *Wizard* eher als eine Art Gelehrten sieht, den *Sorcerer* eher in die Richtung eines Chemikers/Alchemisten und *Warlock* tendenziell als im Bunde mit dem Teufel oder anderen Dämonen stehend.

Mein Wörterbuch übersetzt allerdings alle drei Begriffe mit **Zauberer** oder **Hexer**, was überhaupt gar nicht differenziert. Ich könnte mir bestenfalls noch *Hexer* für eine Übersetzung von *Warlock* vorstellen, da dieser Begriff **manchmal** als männliche Version der *Witch*, also der *Hexe* gebraucht wird. Es blieben dann aber immer noch *Wizard* und *Sorcerer* übrig für die mir nur Zauberer einfällt.

Haben wir im Deutschen ähnliche Begriffe, ggf. mit gleichem Wortstamm?

Comment: Vom Gefühl her ist die englische Sprache im Gebiet der Magie allgemein vielseitiger. Ähnliche Fälle z.B.: spell/charm/enchantment vs. Zauber(spruch), to conjure/summon vs. beschwören oder curse/jinx/hex vs. Fluch/Verwünschung.

Answer (score 8):

Wie schon in der Frage bemerkt, gibt es keine bedeutungserhaltende Übersetzung der drei Begriffe. Deshalb denke ich, dass man dies durch eine Konvention lösen sollte.

### Warlock

Meines Erachtens gibt es mehrere gute Übersetzungen für Warlock. Je nachdem, welche man wählt, bleiben unterschiedliche Begriffe für Sorcerer und Wizard übrig.

**Warlock ist Hexenmeister, weibl. Hexermeisterin.**

Dies passt sowohl zu der historischen Bedeutung einer Hexe als Person, die einen Pakt mit dem Teufel im Tausch gegen magische Kräfte abgeschlossen hat, grenzt aber auch von Märchenbild der Hexe als alter, böser Frau ab. Während 'Hexer' wohl noch passen könnte, ist das Bild, was in einem Fantasy-Kontext durch das Wort 'Hexe' beschworen wird, nicht das, was man sich unter einem weiblichen Warlock vorstellen würde.

**Warlock ist Schwarzmagier**

Dies könnte passen, da Warlock schon einen etwas 'bösen' Beigeschmack hat, sowohl im englischen Umgangsgebrauch wie auch in Dungeons & Dragons. In Deutsch ist aber ein Schwarzmagier immer eindeutig böse, was als Nachteil gesehen werden kann.

Für die Warlock-Klasse in der vierten oder fünften Edition von Dungeons & Dragons käme sonst auch noch die Alternative **Paktmagier** in Frage.

### Wizard und Sorcerer

Wie schon in der Frage bemerkt, ist die Abgrenzung zwischen Sorcerer und Wizard schwieriger.

**Wizard und Sorcerer als Zauberer und Magier**

Man könnte Zauberer als Wizard, und Sorcerer als Magier übersetzen (oder umgekehrt). Die beiden Begriffe bedeuten zwar fast dasselbe in Deutsch, aber das war genau so, als Dungeons und Dragons Wizard und Sorcerer als Klassennamen verwendete. Solange man sich auf eine Konvention einigt und diese konsistent verwendet, löst dies das Problem.

Wenn man hingegen für Warlock das Wort Schwarzmagier verwendet, kann folgende Konvention für Wizard und Sorcerer verwendet werden:

**Wizard ist Zauberer**

Ein Buch-Gelehrter, ein alter Mann mit spitzen Hut entspricht wohl auch dem Verständnis von Leuten ohne viel Hintergrundwissen über Fantasy-Konventionen.

**Sorcerer ist Hexenmeister**

Ein Hexenmeister wäre hier jemand, der intuitiv Magie verwendet, ohne Buchwissen und theoretischen Hintergrund.

Eine **zusätzliche Unterscheidung** könnte sich auch direkt auf die D&D Zauberer-Schulen und Sorcerer-Hintergründe berufen. So könnte man den Wizard je nach Spezialisierung als Beschwörer, Illusionist, Nekromant, Wahrsager (...) bezeichnen, während vielleicht Sorcerer Drachenmagier oder Zufallsmagier sind.

Answer (score 6):

Ich denke, das hängt von der Fantasy-Welt und dem Spielsystem ab, wie Du die Begriffe definierst und mit Leben füllst. Dementsprechend kannst Du Hexenmeister, Hexer, Magier, Zauberer, Magiekundiger, Magus, Magikus oder was auch immer Du im Thesaurus (zB http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/zauberer.php) noch findest, nehmen.

Comment: Welche Wörter würdest Du dann konkret für die von mir umrissene Definition vorschlagen?

Answer (score 3):

Das ist definitiv Konventionssache, weil wir im Deutschen dort keine Nuancen anbringen, also musst du selbst eine Konvention festlegen.

Ich persönlich nehme **Hexenmeister** oder seltener **Hexer** für **Warlock** (Wobei man hier auch aufpassen muss, je nach Fantasy setting gibt es beispielsweise bei witcher und witch also Hexer und Hexe Unterschiede. In DnD sind Hexen beispielsweise eine eigene Spezies.).
Die Wörter mit der Silbe "-hex-" lassen es diabolischer Klingen und passen besser zum warlock, der meistens auch mit dem Teufel im Bunde waren so wie man es Hexen im Mittelalter nachgesagt hat.

Für **Wizard** nehme ich **Zauberer**. Einfach weil ich bei dem Wort sofort an stereotypische Zauberer wie Merlin denken muss mit dem spitzen Hut mit Sternen drauf oder an aus Filmen bekannte wie Gandalf aus Herr der Ringe oder Dumbledoor aus Harry Potter. Diese haben alle gemeinsam, dass sie alt und Weise sind, also mehr zum Gelehrtentyp passen wie wizard im Englischen.

Daher bleibt noch eine Bezeichnung für den **Sorcorer** übrig. Dafür nehme ich **Magier**, einfach weil noch eine andere Bezeichnung benötigt wird.

Für die Unterscheidung von Sorcorer und Wizard nehme ich für gewöhnlich die Unterscheidung aus Dungeons and Dragons. Sorcorer sind solche, die magische Fähigkeiten im Blut haben, also Magie vererrbt bekommen haben oder es auf andere weise bekommen haben ähnlich wie bei Spiderman, der seine Spinnenkräfte durch den Biss einer Radioaktiven Spinne bekommen hat. Zauberer hingegen lernen Magie mehr wie ein Handwerk, das theoretisch jeder lernen könnte, abgesehen davon, dass das Wissen geheimgehalten wird und die Ausbildung anstrengend und lang ist.